# Adding animations to the buttons in sequence within a certain time

Tags: javascript

For example, I have 5 buttons and I have a time of 10 seconds. I'm trying to play animations behind each button, starting from the 1st button, for 2 seconds each. But as I tried below, after playing the animations in sequence, it gets mixed up and the animations of the buttons play randomly. Below are the codes I have tried.

I have one function as follows, and when the time is up, I enter this function and process it.sorry i am new to javascipt i tried this way.Exactly what I want:The animation of the 1st button will play for 2 seconds and it will switch to the animation of the 2nd button, it will play for 2 seconds and will switch to the animation of the 3rd button. So in order

```
function reset() {
            document.getElementById("1").style.animation = "glowing 500ms infinite";
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("1").style.animation = "none";
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("2").style.animation = "glowing 500ms infinite";
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("2").style.animation = "none";
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("3").style.animation = "glowing 500ms infinite";
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("3").style.animation = "none";
            }, 1500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("4").style.animation = "glowing 500ms infinite";
            }, 1500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("4").style.animation = "none";
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("5").style.animation = "glowing 500ms infinite";
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("5").style.animation = "none";
            }, 2500);

}
```

Comment: does it have to be done with `JS` only?

Comment: better way is to manage promises

Comment: I think posting related ```html``` and ```css``` code could help other better help you. Also when and how you call ```reset``` function?

Comment: I have 25 seconds and after 10 seconds it starts counting down from 25 again. I want to play animation in this 10 second space. @hamid-davodi

Comment: what else can i do? @UmairFarooq

Comment: it's unclear, do you want all the animations to run together or one after the other, or overlapping in sequences?

Comment: The animation of the 1st button will play for 2 seconds and it will switch to the animation of the 2nd button, it will play for 2 seconds and will switch to the animation of the 3rd button. So in order @MisterJojo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I told you in my first comment (to which you did not react), you must use a chain of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

- there are a lot of technical things to know [(the MDN doc is there for that)](https://developer.mozilla.org)
  and I'm not some kind of teacher; anyway StackOverflow is not an online college.

start with [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/GeneratorFunction)

However, if you have any questions... ;)
-- but SO is already full of questions and answers on many technical points used here

this can result in JS code like this:

```js
const 
  [btA, btB, btC, btD, btE] = [...document.querySelectorAll('#btns > button')]
, delay             = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
, animLoopGenerator = function* ()
  {
  const animLoop = 
    [ { stop: null, start: btA,  time_ms: 2000 } 
    , { stop: btA,  start: btB,  time_ms: 2000 }
    , { stop: btB,  start: btC,  time_ms: 2000 }
    , { stop: btC,  start: btD,  time_ms: 2000 }
    , { stop: btD,  start: btE,  time_ms: 2000 }
    , { stop: btE,  start: null, time_ms: null }
    ];
  for (let elm of animLoop) yield elm;
  };
async function do_Animtions()
  { 
  for await ( { stop, start, time_ms } of animLoopGenerator() )
    {
    if (stop)    stop.classList.remove('glowing500');
    if (start)   start.classList.add('glowing500');
    if (time_ms) await delay(time_ms);
    }
  }
btnTest.onclick = async () =>  // testing
  {
  btnTest.disabled = true;
  await do_Animtions();
  btnTest.disabled = false;
  }
```

```css
#btns > button
  {
  padding          : .2em 1em .3em 1em;
  border           : 1px solid black;
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  }
.glowing500 
  {
  animation : glowing 500ms infinite; 
  }
@keyframes glowing 
  {
  50%  { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: blue }
  }
```

```html
<div id="btns">
  <button>Number1</button>
  <button>Number2</button>
  <button>Number3</button>
  <button>Number4</button>
  <button>Number5</button>
</div>

<br> <button id="btnTest"> test animation </button>
```

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you for your reply. I have a problem here, after playing animation on the last button it doesn't start again. if(stop) part anim.stop.classList.remove('glowing500'); If I type, it starts again, but when removing animations, the buttons flicker and a bad image appears. If I type replace as you did, it doesn't start either. What would be the reason ? @MisterJojo

Comment: @kennedyforf Right... let's just say that I would also have liked you to have read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with especially the [reproducible example link in part](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because I got tired of having to guess and rewrite css and HTML to develop a snippet, and check that it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what you want because you didnt provide actual css and html but you can delay animations with css like this.hope it helps

```css
.btn {
        padding: 10px 30px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
        animation: glowing 2s;
    }

    .btn:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    .btn:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: 4s;
    }
    .btn:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    .btn:nth-child(5) {
        animation-delay: 8s;
    }

    @keyframes glowing {
        50% {
            background-color: red;
        }

        100% {
            background-color: blue
        }
    }
```

```html
    <button class="btn">Number1</button>
    <button class="btn">Number2</button>
    <button class="btn">Number3</button>
    <button class="btn">Number4</button>
    <button class="btn">Number5</button>
```